# How to display additional info for a completion option in second popup menu

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc, popup-menu

The coc.nvim plugin has a really cool feature where the completion, or at least the python completion, will have additional information about the option in a second popup menu. I have looked through a good deal of vim documentation on completion and I cannot find any way to do this. Does anyone know how to get this to work with custom completions, not using coc.nvim?

[image]

Comment: It was originally in a preview window; recently support for a second popup was added (I forget the name of the option)

Comment: Try `completeopt` with `popup`, and `completepopup`

Comment: Setting completeopt to have either of these options returns an error for me.

Comment: The latter is a separate option. You may need a newer vim

Comment: I just installed the latest neovim-nightly from the AUR and both still return errors.

Comment: Ah; i dont know how it works for neovim.